# Share xaml.cs files

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using a shared library to share some of my code. Is it possible to share the xaml.cs files for XAML page templates in the same way by putting them into the shared library?

Comment: well. yes. did you try it? I guess that you did but then maybe you got some issues using it. If you did, may I suggest explaining that issue instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `UserControl` and reuse that class in your xaml.cs files:

```
public class MyBaseControl : UserControl
{
    // shared functionality
}
```

and your XAML files look like this:

```
<local:MyBaseControl x:Class="MyApp.CoolUserControl"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:MyBaseControl>
```

and your xaml.cs files:

```
public sealed partial class CoolUserControl : MyBaseControl
{
   public CoolUserControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!